# UICollectionViewCell scrolls when UITextView is tapped, doesn't scroll back when keyboard dismissed

Tags: ios, ipad, uiscrollview, uitextview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UITextView` in a `UIScrollView` in a `UICollectionViewCell`, and when I tap it, everything scrolls up for the keyboard, but it never scrolls down when I close the keyboard.

This problem only occurs when everything is inside a `UICollectionViewCell`

I have not added any code to cause the scrolling up, in fact the `UICollectionViewCell` isn't even a delegate of the `UITextView`

Has anyone run into this? Or does anyone know how to disable it from scrolling up altogether when the keyboard appears?

Thanks for any help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this finally. I thought that because my `UICollectionViewCell` has a `UIScrollView` in it, that the content in the `UIScrollView` was being scrolled up. What was actually happening was the `UICollectionView` was actually moving the frame of the entire `UICollectionViewCell` up 200 pixels when the keyboard appeared, but wasn't moving it back down when the keyboard disappeared, so I just made the `UICollectionViewCell` a delegate of the `UITextView` and when it ended editing I reset the cell's origin to (0, 0)